# Openlayers google map getTileBounds

Tags: openlayers

how do I get the bounds of a tile given a point in openlayers using google map v3 as a baselayer. I am unable to getTileBounds(kaMap:second link) and I can't getTileSize(GoogleMap).

http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Google/v3-js.html

http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/KaMap-js.html

Example of my code:

```
 getTileInformationForPoint : function(point) {
    var layer = this.map.baseLayer;

    //Get the bounds of the tile that encases point
    var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(point.getLongitude(), point.getLatitude());
    lonLat = lonLat.transform('EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857');
    var viewPortPixel = this.map.getViewPortPxFromLonLat(lonLat);
    var tileBounds = layer.getTileBounds(viewPortPixel);
```

Answer (score 0):

[OpenLayers.Layer.Grid.getTileBounds()](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Grid-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Grid.getTilesBounds) looks like it returns a Bounds around the entire tile grid - all the tiles currently loaded.  This doesn't look like what you need.

Have you tried [OpenLayers.Layer.Grid.getTileData()](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Grid-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Grid.getTileData) where you pass in a lat/lon location and it gives you an OpenLayers.Tile object back?  You can then call getBoundsFromBaseLayer() on the Tile object.

Comment: Hi, I create the map using new OpenLayers.Layer.Google and not grid and I am unable to find any examples on creating a google layer ontop of a grid layer if that is even possible.

Comment: Hi, I didn't see your comment response until now.  I misunderstood thinking you were trying to get the bounds of a Grid/WMS layer that sat on top of a Google base layer.  I looked around the API and at my data in firebug and I don't see a way to get bounds information of the Google tiles on your map.  So much is out of your control or sight with the Google layer.